# How to get the VID and PID of all USB devices connected to my system in .net?

Tags: .net, usb

In a C#.net console application, what code can i write to print on the screen the VID and PID of each USB  device connected to the system?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8572

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some code I've written based on what I've found so far.  There may be a better way to do this.

```
    public static void MyMethod()
    {                            
        System.Management.ManagementClass USBClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_USBDevice");                
        System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection USBCollection = USBClass.GetInstances();

        foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject usb in USBCollection)
        {
            string deviceId = usb["deviceid"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(deviceId);

            int vidIndex = deviceId.IndexOf("VID_");
            string startingAtVid = deviceId.Substring(vidIndex + 4); // + 4 to remove "VID_"                    
            string vid = startingAtVid.Substring(0, 4); // vid is four characters long
            Console.WriteLine("VID: " + vid);

            int pidIndex = deviceId.IndexOf("PID_");
            string startingAtPid = deviceId.Substring(pidIndex + 4); // + 4 to remove "PID_"                    
            string pid = startingAtPid.Substring(0, 4); // pid is four characters long
            Console.WriteLine("PID: " + pid);                                        
        }            

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```