# How can I find the PID (Product ID) and VID (Vendor ID) of my devices in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the PID (Product ID) and VID (Vendor ID) of a device

I already found this post that ask the same question: [How to get the VID and PID of all USB devices connected to my system in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303069/how-to-get-the-vid-and-pid-of-all-usb-devices-connected-to-my-system-in-net) 
However I'm getting an exception in the ManagementClass constructor saying that it wouldn't find Win32_USBDevice

I found a suggestion of passing "Win32_DiskDrive" as a parameter instead but then it doesn't find anything and throw a NullReferenceException at the end of the scope (seems like it's related to IDiposable because adding "using" to the like make it throw there)

So my question is, how can I get the PID and VID of my devices using C# and .NET6?

Comment: A PID belongs to a process, do you have a process, specific for your device? And what's a VID?

Comment: PID and VID are unique ID for a device
https://www.oshwa.org/2013/11/19/new-faq-on-usb-vendor-id-and-product-id/

Comment: Oh, PID means "Product ID"? PID is commonly known as "Process ID". You might be confusing quite some people, here :-)

Comment: Should I update the title of the question?

Comment: Yes, updating the title and the question itself is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried a WMI query? This should be pretty straightforward to get the device id

```
public class CustomWMIQuery
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE InterfaceType='USB'");

            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Caption: {0}", queryObj["Caption"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);
                Console.WriteLine("DeviceID: {0}", queryObj["DeviceID"]);
                Console.WriteLine("PNPDeviceID: {0}", queryObj["PNPDeviceID"]);
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The device id looks somthing like this

```
  USB\VID_0911&PID_1240&MI_01\6&27AAD51C&0&0000
```

You can then take the information from **VID_** to the next **&** seperator as the vendor Id
You can then take the information from **PID_** to the next **&** seperator as the product Id